# Nim Game Java errors?

Tags: java, syntax-error

Hi I am programming a game of Nim,

I ha e most of the code complete but I am having two major problems.

1. I can't find my errors
2. I can't seem to get the computer to take its turn

Thanks in advance, here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
public class Nim {


public static void main(String[] args) {
int banana = 0;
Random r = new Random();
    intro();
    banana = r.nextInt(16);
    int numStones = (15 + banana);
yorner(numStones);


//kbinput.nextInt();



        }
public static void intro () {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Nim!");
    System.out.println("The Rules of the game are as follows: \n");
System.out.println("1. There are two players in this game; you and the computer.");
    System.out.println("2. The game starts with a random number stones ranging from 15 to 30 stones.");
System.out.println("3. Every turn each player takes anywhere between 1 to 3 stones");
    System.out.println("4. The player who takes the last stone loses. \n");
System.out.println("Would you like to start the game now? \nPlease enter 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no:");

}
public static void yorner (int numStones){
System.out.println("This game of nim will start with " + numStones + " stones.\n");
    Scanner kbinput = new Scanner (System.in);
    boolean vInput = false;

    do
        {
        String yorn = kbinput.nextLine();
        char input = yorn.charAt(0);
        switch(input) { 

    case 'Y':
    case 'y':
        vInput = true;
        yes(numStones);
        break;
    case 'N':
    case 'n':
        System.out.println("Thank you for your time.");
        vInput = true;
        break;
    default:
System.out.println("Please only enter 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no, other entries will not be tolerated.");
        }
        }
        while((vInput == false));

}
public static void yes (int numStones){
System.out.println("You selected 'Yes', thank you for choosing to play the game of  Nim.\n");

    System.out.println("It is your turn first.");
    System.out.println("How many stones would you like to take? \n");
    System.out.println("Enter a number from 1 to 3");
    player(numStones);
}

public static  int player(int numStones){


    Scanner kbinput = new Scanner (System.in);
    int numTake = kbinput.nextInt();
    int numStone = 0;
    boolean apple = false;
    loop: while ( apple == false){
    switch(numTake){
    case 1:
        apple = true;
        numStone  = numStones - numTake;
        System.out.println("There are " + numStone + " stones left");
        break;
    case 2:
        apple = true;
        numStone = numStones - numTake;
        System.out.println("There are " + numStone + " stones left");
        break;
    case 3:
        apple = true;
        numStone = numStones - numTake;
        System.out.println("There are " + numStone + " stones left");

        break;
    default:
System.out.println("You can only takes anywhere between 1 and 3 stones from the pile"); 
    }
        }

    return numStone;

}
public static boolean compWin (int numStone){
return false;

}
public static void computerTurn(int numStone1, int numStone) {
Random rn = null;
int compTake = rn.nextInt(3);
switch(compTake){
case 1:
    System.out.println("Computer takes 1 stone.");
    numStone1  = numStone - compTake;
    System.out.println("There are " + numStone + " stones left");
    break;
case 2:
    System.out.println("Computer takes 2 stones");
    numStone1 = numStone - compTake;
    System.out.println("There are " + numStone + " stones left");
    break;
case 3:
    System.out.println("Computer takes 3 stones");
    numStone1 = numStone - compTake;
    System.out.println("There are " + numStone + " stones left");
    break;
}
}






}
```

The errors that I get are these

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

Comment: `Random rn = null;
int compTake = rn.nextInt(3);`

I'm pretty sure this will always result in a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Similar to how you have the Random variable in your `main` method.  Rather than `null`, initialize it.  `Random rn = new Random();`

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your compilation error.

However, you do not have a game loop (that is, a loop that keeps the game going while there are still valid moves) and you never invoke the `computerTurn`

Comment: could you help me on how to do this?

Comment: In your main, something like: `while (numStones > 0) { player(); computerTurn(); }`. You do not need the first argument in `computerTurn()` btw. Since you overwrite it anyway, just declare it at the start of the method.